# How can I refactor this particular piece of codes?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, refactoring

I'm new to programming, currently trying to refactor this piece of code, the function of this chunk of codes is to replace the whitespace in the column names with '_', here's the codes:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
labels[0] = labels[0].replace(' ', '_')
labels[1] = labels[1].replace(' ', '_')
labels[2] = labels[2].replace(' ', '_')
labels[3] = labels[3].replace(' ', '_')
labels[5] = labels[5].replace(' ', '_')
labels[6] = labels[6].replace(' ', '_')
df.columns = labels
```

How can I refactor it and maybe make it reusable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def fun(label):
    return label.replace(' ', '_')
df.columns = map(fun, df.columns)
```